# APA106 random color when power applied

Tags: rgb-led, neopixel

The APA106 RGB LED is usually blue when 5VDC is applied. Sometimes it is a random color when turning the power supply on and off. How to keep it a consistent color when power is applied?

Normal:
[image: normal blue apa106]

Sometimes:
[image: sometimes random color apa106]

It’s for an Arduino project, I’ve just isolated the problem to the LED. Dozens of these exhibit this behaviour. The PCB board in the pictures is just a breadboard power supply.

**Update:** DIN to GND still exhibits the same behaviour.

[image: din to gnd still pink]

Here is a demo of the problem. 90% of the time at power up the LEDs is blue, but occasionally the color is random like pink or white.

[YouTube link to a 38s clip of the problem manifesting](https://youtu.be/bITeGnsc7T8)

**Update:** At Robert's suggestion, I modified the V-USB [bootloader](https://github.com/ericdraken/micronucleus) to send the control bits and timings to immediately turn off the APA106 LED. There is still an extremely brief blue pulse (or random color) because power applied to the LED is always faster than any CPU process. It's not perfect, but better.

Comment: Did you apply a RESET pulse/code (DIN to GND)? Might need to be longer than 50us.

Comment: Leaving the DIN pin floating will give undetermined results. Try connecting the DIN pin to ground.

Comment: @Gerben Great thought, but DIN to GND still exhibits this behaviour. Also in my Adruino project the DIN pin is connected to the GPIO and not left floating. I’ve isolated the issue to the LED. Thx.

Comment: @MikaelPatel These LEDs are straight out of the manufacturer’s packaging and 90% of the time are blue when they are powered. I’ve removed all Ardruino circuity to demonstrate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Wire it to the MCU such that power is first applied to the LED under control of the sketch when the sketch is prepared to immediately set the initial color you want. The time taken to accomplish the (power up, set initial color) will have to be less than the eye's ability to perceive the possible color glitch (which, being relatively slow compared to the Arduino, it should be pretty easy to do).

Update:

> There is still an extremely brief blue pulse

That remaining delay is probably the IDE's reset-pulse duration plus the Arduino board's R-C delay on the reset pin. It's probably the best you can do without a lot of hardware (e.g. a switch on every R/G/B pin, designed to power-up "off".)

Comment: Thanks, Robert. In lieu of anything else I can do, I modified the bootloader to send the control bits to turn off the APA106 LED. There is still an extremely brief blue pulse because the power is always faster than any CPU process. The random color still manifests, but it's brief. Thanks for the suggestion.